# Kotlin: variadic (auto-infer) type arguments possible?

Tags: generics, kotlin, variadic-functions, type-inference

I understood how basic type inference works in Kotlin, but i wonder if i can only call a function with either all type arguments or none of them, or if i can define variable type arguments somehow; EG:

```
fun<A: SomeClass1, B: SomeClass2, T: SomeTuple<A,B>> foo(t:SomeTuple<A,B>?=null) = doSomething<A,B,T>(t)
```

this function can either be called via `foo(someTuple)` or `foo<SomeClass1,SomeClass2,SomeTuple<Someclass1,SomeClass2>>()`, while it's clear that the first two type arguments are inferable from the last;

Is it possible to do something like `foo<SomeTuple<Someclass1,SomeClass2>>()` and still be able to infer and use `A` and `B` inside the function body

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Can you explain the context of your issue with a more concrete example? Maybe there's a different solution

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do here. If you want to interact with the specifics of your possible generic types, and they differ meaningfully, you are at some point going to have to do some type based conditional logic.  Have a look at sealed classes and when statement?

Comment: @gpunto @Laurence Please take a look at this somewhat realistic example: https://pl.kotl.in/AUDm_rQYH Note that `Handlers.register<HelloWorld, String> { println(it) }` works but `Handlers.register<HelloWorld> { println(it) }` gives a compiler error. However, the second type parameter is clearly inferrable.